# How can one set elements on top of the Applicationbar (or have the layout be aware of it)?

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, appbar

To clarify, I want to have my ApplicationBar resting on top of my LayoutRoot grid. The desired effect would be like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    </Grid>
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
</StackPanel>
```

Of course, the above code doesn't work because the  must be in the root tag of the page, but I do wish it did.

Does anyone know a way that I can create this effect? It doesn't have to be a perfect solution, just something that replicates it and will work on any resolution.

By request, I'll elaborate more on the specific problem.

The picture below is what I currently have:

[image: current layout]

I want the 'Specular Light' control to 'rest' on top of the app bar, like so:

[image: correct layout]

And lastly but certainly not least, here is the relevant XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <DrawingSurface x:Name="DrawingSurfaceBackground" Loaded="DrawingSurfaceBackground_Loaded" />
    <ScrollViewer Name="LightControl" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Grid Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Ambient Light" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
            <Slider Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="AmbientLightSlider" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="2.0"  
                Value="1.0" ValueChanged="AmbientLightSlider_OnValueChanged" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Diffuse Light" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
            <Slider Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="DiffuseLightSlider" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="2.0"  
                Value="1.0" ValueChanged="DiffuseLightSlider_OnValueChanged" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Specular Light" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
            <Slider Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="SpecularLightSlider" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="2.0"  
                Value="1.0" ValueChanged="SpecularLightSlider_OnValueChanged" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Toolkit.Content/ApplicationBar.Center.png" Text="Center" Click="Center_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Toolkit.Content/ApplicationBar.Wireframe.png" Text="Wireframe" Click="Rasterizer_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Toolkit.Content/ApplicationBar.Center.png" Text="Light" Click="Light_Click" />
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Thank you for reading and for your help.

Comment: that is not a problem with where your application bar is defined. It is clear that you have a problem on your xaml code under Layout root. Please post the XAML code - it should be easy to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here are two solutions:

The first one is with the application bar not being transparent:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <DrawingSurface x:Name="DrawingSurfaceBackground" Loaded="DrawingSurfaceBackground_Loaded" />
    <ScrollViewer Name="LightControl" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Grid Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Ambient Light" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
            <Slider Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="AmbientLightSlider" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="2.0"  
                Value="1.0" ValueChanged="AmbientLightSlider_OnValueChanged" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Diffuse Light" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
            <Slider Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="DiffuseLightSlider" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="2.0"  
                Value="1.0" ValueChanged="DiffuseLightSlider_OnValueChanged" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Specular Light" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
            <Slider Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="SpecularLightSlider" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="2.0"  
                Value="1.0" ValueChanged="SpecularLightSlider_OnValueChanged" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Toolkit.Content/ApplicationBar.Center.png" Text="Center" Click="Center_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Toolkit.Content/ApplicationBar.Wireframe.png" Text="Wireframe" Click="Rasterizer_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Toolkit.Content/ApplicationBar.Center.png" Text="Light" Click="Light_Click" />
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

I actually have changed the height of the `ScrollViewer`: `Height="150"` so only two sliders will fit and completely removed the opacity from the app bar: `Opacity="0"`.

Now with transparent application bar:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <DrawingSurface x:Name="DrawingSurfaceBackground" Loaded="DrawingSurfaceBackground_Loaded" />
    <ScrollViewer Name="LightControl" Height="150" Margin="0,0,0,70" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Grid Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Ambient Light" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
            <Slider Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="AmbientLightSlider" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="2.0"  
                Value="1.0" ValueChanged="AmbientLightSlider_OnValueChanged" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Diffuse Light" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
            <Slider Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="DiffuseLightSlider" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="2.0"  
                Value="1.0" ValueChanged="DiffuseLightSlider_OnValueChanged" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Specular Light" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
            <Slider Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="SpecularLightSlider" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="2.0"  
                Value="1.0" ValueChanged="SpecularLightSlider_OnValueChanged" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Opacity="0">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Toolkit.Content/ApplicationBar.Center.png" Text="Center" Click="Center_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Toolkit.Content/ApplicationBar.Wireframe.png" Text="Wireframe" Click="Rasterizer_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Toolkit.Content/ApplicationBar.Center.png" Text="Light" Click="Light_Click" />
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Since you ask for the application bar to be transparent the UI element(s), in your case the `ScrollViewer`, knows that the end of the page is actually where the application bar ends. So by adding 70 margin from bottom: `Margin="0,0,0,70"` would fix the "on top" problem.

Comment: Ah sorry, the transparent application bar was left over from me trying another answerer's advice. But awesome answer! So question: Does the Margin="0,0,0,70" translate proportionally when other resolutions are tested? I'll definitely test this but that would awesome if it did. Thank you for the help, I'll come back and update if all worked well. PS: also thanks for the 150 height tip.

Comment: The answer is yes! I thought Margin was an absolute pixel based positioning attribute but it automagically adjusts for other resolutions. Win!

Comment: Actually its not 70 precisely but 72 - 70 looks better though ;) check this out: "The App Bar height in portrait mode and width in landscape mode is fixed at 72 pixels and can’t be modified. The app bar can be set to be displayed or hidden."

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the AppBar Layout position, nor positioning it inside another element. It Always need to be  declared at page level, as ApplicationBar is a property of the page itself, not a UIElement, FrameworkElement or Control property.

I don't understand exactly what you mean as "rest on top of my layout grid" If you want your layout grid be (in Z order) below your ApplicationBar, you can add the Opacity property with a value lower than 1 to the ApplicationBar, this way the page content use the full page and the ApplicationBar is positioned on top of the content. is this the effect you want? If not, please help me understand what you want to achieve (maybe a little image drawn with Paint can help to understand the visual effect you want)

Comment: I can do better than that, I've provided some screenshots and updated the original posting. Also thanks for helping.

Comment: Hi Nico, thanks for the screenshots, very clarifying! When you put the appbar Without opacity it should reposition all your content above it. This effect seems to happen because you are using fixed sizes for your elements, so them need more room than that available in the screen. Can you put some of your xaml code for the layout?

Comment: Setting the opacity to 0 doesn't seem to have done what I wanted (although it does look nicer). here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/89DzcKh.jpg I have also edited the question to include the XAML code in question.